# can't add Application to displaylist

Tags: apache-flex, swfloader

I'm trying to use a SWFLoader to load an Application and add the loaded Application to my Displaylist.

```
public function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    someContainer.addChild((e.target.content));
}

//somewhere in main
var loader: SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(urlToSwf);
```

I'm getting the errormessage

```
cannot convert _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager@c513eb9 to mx.core.IUIComponent
```

Could anybody tell me why this won't work or how i can fix this?

Thanks,
Sims

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not recommend you to load Flex applications into another Flex applications. There are ready to use Modules present in Flex framework. You can read more details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f22.html).

What about your case in particular you should [read `addChild()` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#addChild%28%29):

> Note: While the child argument to the
>   method is specified as of type
>   DisplayObject, the argument must
>   implement the IUIComponent interface
>   to be added as a child of a container.
>   All Flex components implement this
>   interface.

So you can add `UIComponent` first and the add your system manager there.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say the same thing.  Modules man.  They're not hard to create.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because what you are trying to add to stage is of type SystemManager and of course you want to add your application to the display list.

So try this:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.SystemManager;

        private var _systemManager:SystemManager;

        protected function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            _systemManager = SystemManager(loader.content);
            _systemManager.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onApplicationComplete);
        }

        private function onApplicationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            mainContainer.addChild(_systemManager.application);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:SWFLoader id="loader" source="main.swf" width="800" height="600" autoLoad="true" complete="onLoaderComplete(event)"/>

<mx:VBox id="mainContainer"/>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but it still won't work. I'm getting the errorMessage cannot convert _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager@3ca6eb9 to mx.managers.SystemManager.

Comment: Are you sure that you have copy pasted this correctly?

When I run this in my Flash builder it works perfectly.

Comment: I hope i did so... I'm writing actionscriptCode and not FlexCode if that makes any difference.

Comment: Nope that should not make any difference. Because mxml will be converted to generated ActionScript by your compiler.
Have a closer look to what is in the example and do it exactly as stated. Works perfectly on my machine...

Also, make sure that both your flex applications are compiled with the same SDK, otherwise you will get other error messages as well

Answer (score 0):

Just add the SWFLoader to the container.

```
public function loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:SWFLoader = event.target as SWFLoader;
    someContainer.addChild(loader);
}

//somewhere in main
var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);
loader.load(urlToSwf);
```

Comment: Thats what im trying now. I want to manipulate some Objects in the loaded application but i dont get over the SystemManger somehow.. Thats my problem now.